# Creating formulas in R involving an arbitrary number of variables

Tags: r

I'm using the library poLCA. To use the main command of the library one has to create a formula as follows:

```
f <- cbind(V1,V2,V3)~1
```

After this a command is invoked:

```
poLCA(f,data0,...)
```

V1, V2, V3 are the names of variables in the dataset data0. I'm running a simulation and I need to change the formula several times. Sometimes it has 3 variables, sometimes 4, sometimes more.

If I try something like:

```
f <- cbind(get(names(data0)[1]),get(names(data0)[2]),get(names(data0)[3]))~1
```

it works fine. But then I have to know in advance how many variables I will use. I would like to define an arbitrary vector

```
vars0 <- c(1,5,17,21)
```

and then create the formula as follows

```
f<- cbind(get(names(data0)[var0]))
```

Unfortunaly I get an error. I suspect the answer may involve some form of apply but I still don't understand very well how this functions work. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Using data from the examples in `?poLCA` this (possibly hackish) idiom seems to work:

```
library(poLCA)
vec <- c(1,3,4)
M4 <- poLCA(do.call(cbind,values[,vec])~1,values,nclass = 1)
```

*Edit*

As Hadley points out in the comments, we're making this a bit more complicated than we need. In this case `values` is a data frame, not a matrix, so this:

```
M1 <- poLCA(values[,c(1,2,4)]~1,values,nclass = 1)
```

generates an error, but this:

```
M1 <- poLCA(as.matrix(values[,c(1,2,4)])~1,values,nclass = 1)
```

works fine. So you can just subset the columns as long as you wrap it in `as.matrix`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong w/ using do.call. It's a great tnterpretation tool, along with as.name and similar functions.

Comment: I understand why it seems hackish, but the other way to build a formula, with `paste` operations and `as.formula` seems pretty hackish, too.

Comment: Don't see why you need do.call here. Why doesn't subsetting values give you a matrix?

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you. Problem fixed. I posted my question late on a Saturday night and Sunday morning I have an answer. Is Stackoverflow.com an awesome or what? :-)

Comment: @user950899 If either answer solved your problem, please click the check mark next to the one you prefer, so that others viewing this question will see that you received a solution that worked.

Answer (score 2):

@DWin mentioned building the formula with `paste` and `as.formula`.  I thought I'd show you what that would look like using the `election` dataset.

```
library("poLCA")
data(election)

vec <- c(1,3,4)

f <- as.formula(paste("cbind(",paste(names(election)[vec],collapse=","),")~1",sep=""))
```